# What exception will be thrown when a rate limit is reached

Tags: java, amazon-ses

I want to backoff when the rate limit has been reached, what exception is thrown or what happens when an exception is thrown?

Is there a way to know that I should just sleep for x minutes before trying again?

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about the Amazon SES rate limit, since you've tagged the question as such, but your question might get more attention if you provide more context and mention SES in the title or question text itself.

Answer (score 0):

in amazon-ses [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/api-error-codes.html) it reads Throttling error code will be thrown once the rate limit is exceeded.

> Depending on which Amazon SES interface you call, the error is passed
>   back to you differently:
>
> With the Amazon SES HTTP Query interface the error will be received as
>   a “Throttling” error response with a “Maximum sending rate exceeded.”
>   message. With the SMTP interface, Amazon SES responds with “454
>   Throttling failure: Maximum sending rate exceeded” after the DATA
>   command.

For full answer on how to handle Throttling error code check:

[How to handle a "Throttling – Maximum sending rate exceeded" error](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/how-to-handle-a-throttling-maximum-sending-rate-exceeded-error/)